# LL(1) predictive parsing -- Avoid Left recursion

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

When defining a grammar, say a grammar to evaluate an arithmetic expression: we divide the Expression to Terms and Factors, like so:

```
E ::= E + T  
T ::= T * F  
F ::= num  
    | (E)
```

*Then we need to resolve left recursion.*

So why not define the grammar like so:

```
E ::= T + E  
T ::= F * T  
F := num  
    | (E)
```

*And have only right recursion.*

Comment: Your grammar is infinitely recursive.  Can you update it so that derivations eventually terminate?

Comment: The right recursive grammar must terminate as we will run out of raw text to parse...  The same as the left recursive grammar...

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify.  Right now, once you have a production with E in it, there is no way to get rid of the E because the only production for E yields a string containing E; the same is true for T.  Consequently, it's impossible to derive anything.

Comment: @user1497197:  To resolve templatetypedef's complaint, you need to add `E ::= T` and `T ::= F`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that it gets the associativity wrong -- a left-recursive grammar is left associative while a right-recursive grammar is right associative.  Since associativity doesn't matter for `+` or `*` you don't see a problem, but if you add an operator (such as `-`) for which associativity DOES matter, you see the problem.

Note that the way that you deal with left recursion in an LL grammar is essentially by converting to right recursion and then post-processing the parse tree to turn it back into left recursion.  Breaking it down, you convert to

```
E ::= T + E | T
```

which you then left-factor into

```
E ::= T E'
E' ::= \epsilon | + E
```

this will parse the expression `T + T + T` as

```
  E
 / \
T   E'
   / \
  +   E
     / \
    T   E'
       / \
      +   E
         / \
        T   E'
            |
         \epsilon
```

which you then evaluate by treating it as a linked list of alternating terms and operators which you evaluate/perform top to bottom (left to right):

```
tmp1 = eval_term(pop list head)
while (list not empty)
    op = pop list head
    tmp2 = eval_term(pop list head)
    tmp1 = tmp1 op tmp2
```

Answer (score 0):

In the specific example you show, order doesn't matter, so you can swap operands.
But that is not the case for all the other grammars, because moving their symbols may change their meaning; so you *need* to find another way to eliminate left recursion.